# simplest way to download tip/head revision from a sourceforge git repository?

Tags: git, sourceforge

I want to download the source files from a project in sourceforge with a git repository.

But I don't have git, I don't know how to use git, and I'm running on Windows on a network that doesn't allow ssh access.

What's the simplest way for me to download the source tree?

---

**edit:** <strike>I finally found a .zip file containing the source for this particular project in its "Files" section, so this question is now a moot point for me for now. But I'd still like to know if there's an answer for future reference.</strike> Never mind, the source file .zip is incomplete and excludes test cases. >:(

Comment: @#%#$%$#%@$%@# -- after unsuccessfully downloading 3 different Git tools, the last one (GitExtensions) finally "worked" only to fail because of the ssh firewall. >:( RANT RANT RANT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was no good answer. I ended up installing GitExtensions and going through the pain of using git on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Code -> HTTP  -> click on Download Snapshot :)

Comment: A working solution - no need to downvote in my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

many git repositories allow http (github does). Maybe sourceforge does too. You probably need git installed though. It's easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

go to source forge. Click on source tab. click "git browse". Now there should be a summary, shortlog, log, tree set of links. Click on "tree". This will download all the source for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "This will download all the source for you." -- it doesn't.

Comment: when you click on tree you will have the option to dl everything

Comment: Maybe in the project you're looking at, but not the one that I am looking at. (It's jchart2d -- http://jchart2d.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=jchart2d/jchart2d;a=tree )

Comment: hmm, doesn't download it for me, just lets me browse it.